# Slim php framework using nginx , with CORS enabled , request status is 200 but response data is not coming

Tags: php, nginx

I am using slim php framework using nginx , i have enabled CORS also . Now when i make a request to my Rest API from some other domain, the option method is invoked first , then post method is invoked with actual post data.
Response for POST is 200 but there is no data coming from API .

But when i try the same with same domain , everything works perfect.

## WORKING

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://172.19.4.130/oam_restapi/restapi/loginpost",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain:true,
    data : JSON.stringify({
            "username" : "admin",
            "password" : "admin!23B",
            "domain" : "local"
            }),
    success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
        
     
    }

});
```

when this ajax call is made like 172.19.4.130/makeajax.html

## Not working

When this same call is made like localhost/makeajax.html

I understand CORS , and the same was working with APACHE earlier

Nginx Configuration

```
location /oam_restapi/restapi/ { 
    satisfy any;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    root /html/oam_restapi/restapi/; 
    index index.php; 
    try_files $uri /oam_restapi/restapi/index.php; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response from the backend.

Have a look at https://github.com/palanik/CorsSlim